# system.out.print shows as system.outprint isntead

Tags: java

I am currently using Eclipse to code Java with. Recently my lecturer noticed that my print statements in my Java is weird and he does not know a fix to it. It shows `System.outprintln()` instead of `System.out.println()`. When I change it to `System.out.println()` it is underlined with a red line.

Is there a quick fix? He says that I might get marks deducted if I submit my codes in this format without changing it.

Comment: Does it even compile with `System.outprintln()`?

Comment: I'm going to guess you've defined your own class called `System`, with an `outprintln` method. The quick fix is to rename this class.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use full named class:

```
java.lang.System.out.println("some value");
```

If this case would work correctly - you have some mistake with class naming (possibly in manner like in Andy Turner's comment)

PS It would be much easier to assume the reason of problem if you'll provide sketches of your sources.

Answer (score 0):

`out` is static data member of `System` class having type of `PrintStream`.

`println()` is overloaded method of `PrintStream` class.

`System.outprintln()` is compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile the class using command prompt using the following command- `javac myclass.java` and then run it using `java myclass`.

`System.outprintln()` should throw a compiler error.

Please note that any IDE is user friendly and helps to write your code faster by providing suggestions but your assignments should not be based completely on them. :)

Comment: OP hasn't provided his/her code, so you don't know what he/she has in the code. Attempting to replicate it and finding something different is meaningless.

Comment: Its not about replicating but to make OP understand that IDE compiler could be wrong as it is not same as javac.